# IEnumerable lambda expression for Where()

Tags: c#, linq, expression, ienumerable, iqueryable

following code works on a collection of type `IQueryable`:

`Expression<Func<Activity, bool>> filter = e => e.IsDeleted && e.CategoryId == 1;`

But this expression doesn't work on collections of type `IEnumerable`.

How I have to modify my expression to get it working?

In my real scenario, my collection object is a navigation property of an entity framework model class: `person.Activities.Where(filter);`

These are the errors:

```
Error 1
Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Application.Models.Activity>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Application.Models.Activity>'

Error 2
'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Application.Models.Activity>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Where<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,bool>>)' has some invalid arguments
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How I have to modify my expression to get it working?

Just use a delegate instead of an expression tree:

```
Func<Activity, bool> filter = e => e.IsDeleted && e.CategoryId == 1;
```

If you *have* to start off with an expression tree, you can either compile that to a delegate:

```
var filterDelegate = filterExpressionTree.Compile();
```

Or use `AsQueryable` to convert your `IEnumerable<T>` to an `IQueryable<T>`:

```
var foo = person.Activies.AsQueryable().Where(filterExpressionTree);
```

I'd personally avoid expression trees unless you actually need to use them though.

Comment: "ICollection<blah> does not contain a definition for 'AsQueryable'" is what I get, when trying to do something similar.

Comment: @vapcguy: Do you have a using statement for System.Linq?

Comment: When faced with a choice to pick `Compile()` or `AsQueryable()`, is there any reason to pick one over the other?

Comment: @Botis: I'm afraid I don't know enough about the implementation details to know the trade-offs involved.